# Comma separated values from pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

i trying to find out if there is away to remove duplicate in my data frame while concatenating the value

example:

```
df
   key  v1  v2
0  1   n/a  a
1  2   n/a  b
2  3   n/a  c
3  2   n/a  d
4  3   n/a  e
```

the out put should be like:

```
 df_out
   key v1   v2
0  1   n/a  a
1  2   n/a  b,d
2  3   n/a  c,e
```

I try using df.drop_duplicates() and some loop to save the v2 column value and nothing yet.
i'm trying to do it nice and clean with out loop by using Pandas.

some one know a way pandas can do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be easy, assuming you have two columns. Use `groupby` + `agg`. `v1` should be aggregated by `first`, and `v2` should be aggregated by `','.join`.

```
df
   key  v1 v2
0    1 NaN  a
1    2 NaN  b
2    3 NaN  c
3    2 NaN  d
4    3 NaN  e
```

```
(df.groupby('key')
   .agg({'v1' : 'first', 'v2' : ','.join})
   .reset_index()
   .reindex(columns=df.columns))

   key  v1   v2
0    1 NaN    a
1    2 NaN  b,d
2    3 NaN  c,e
```

If you have multiple such columns requiring the same aggregation, build an agg dict called `f` and pass it to `agg`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `set`

```
df.groupby('key').agg(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
Out[1255]: 
      v1   v2
key          
1    n/a    a
2    n/a  b,d
3    n/a  c,e
```

Comment: Sorry, hit the rep cap, don't get vote notifications anymore. It'll take me a while to see your answer but I'll see it eventually!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are a legend, even during the holiday , can made it hit the cap , LOL :-)

Comment: Lol, thanks, it is true. I have the Legendary Badge after all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply`

> pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply
>
> GroupBy.apply(func, *args, **kwargs)[source]
>
> ```
> Apply function func group-wise and combine the results together.
> ```

```
df.groupby(["key", "v1"])["v2"].apply(list) # or apply(set) depending on your needs
```

Output:

```
key  v1
1    n/a       [a]
2    n/a    [b, d]
3    n/a    [c, e]
Name: v2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to implement the following code but I have an additional requirement with this where I can have upto 300 joins in 'CONCAT' and the rest should be in separate row/rows. Example: if I have 750 values in 'CONCAT' with similar 'ISSUEID', first 300 will be in row 1, next 300 in row 2 and remaining 150 in row 3. Is there a way I can tweak this?

```
df = (data.groupby('ISSUEID')
   .agg({'KICKCODE' : 'first', 'CONCAT' : ','.join})
   .reset_index()
   .reindex(columns=data.columns))
```